# Is experience the same regardless of level?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When you assign dwellers to a room like the Diner or the Power Generator, they accrue experience, and level up.

Does it take the exact same amount of experience to level up, regardless if the dweller is level 1 or level 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

I can't find a listing of the actual experience amounts required per level anywhere, even on the famous [Reddit spreadsheet](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/3bg1ls/fallout_shelter_explained_via_spreadsheet/).

But, based on my experience playing the game, I'm fairly confident that the answer is no. When I put a level 1 person in a room, they usually level up within a few minutes, whereas someone in the 40's takes hours or days. The first few levels while exploring go pretty quickly, the later ones take longer.